# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

Hey I keep getting an error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

My code:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT FirstName, SecondName, Aboutme FROM User WHERE UserID=1", cn);

OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
    Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Comment: You transposed the index of the argument in the reader with the index of the parameter in the format statement.  Switch 2 with 0 in your `Aboutme.Text = `.

Comment: String.Format does not use unique placeholders per-class nor per-solution. It is per string each time String.Format is called, so please don't increase it to {2} based on {0} and {1} having been used!

Comment: any reason you're using ODBC vs. the .NET connector ?

Comment: Why do you use a string.formar for this row :)  Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));
you could.  Aboutme.Text =reader.GetString(0);

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Your second `String.Format` uses `{2}` as a placeholder but you're only passing in one argument, so you should use `{0}` instead.

Change this:

```
String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));
```

To this:

```
String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
```

Answer (score 26):

In this line:

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));
```

The token {2} is invalid because you only have one item in the parms.  Use this instead:

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 8):

Change this line:

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 7):

This can also happen when trying to throw an `ArgumentException` where you inadvertently call the `ArgumentException` constructor overload

```
public static void Dostuff(Foo bar)
{

   // this works
   throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Could not find {0}", bar.SomeStringProperty));

   //this gives the error
   throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Could not find {0}"), bar.SomeStringProperty);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

String.Format must start with zero index "{0}" like this:

```
Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your FirstName ");
            String FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your LastName ");
            String LastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, {1} ", FirstName, LastName);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Here, when I run this query. In command Line it doesn't print the last line like "Hello Parag Patel" but it is showing error "System.FormatException occurred
Message=Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Comment: It should be Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, {1} ", FirstName, LastName);

Comment: @Fenrir88, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

The 2 should be 0. Every count starts at 0.

```
//Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{2}", reader.GetString(0));//wrong

//Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));//correct
```