# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is the error I get:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

This is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">



public void Page_Load()
{
    string a, c;
    a = Request.Form["username"];

    string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("SQL/Site_Database.accdb");
    string sqlstring = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (iusername='{0}')", a);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstring, connstring);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);


    c = Request.Form["mail"];

    string connstring1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("SQL/Site_Database.accdb");
    string sqlstring1 = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{0}')", c);
    OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstring1, connstring1);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds1);

    if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) || (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0))
    {

        string b, d, e, f, g, h;

        b = Request.Form["password"];
        d = Request.Form["gender"];
        e = Request.Form["age"];
        f = Request.Form["prob"];
        g = Request.Form["prob_val"];
        h = Request.Form["fitness"];

        sqlstring = string.Format("insert into iUsers_Table (iusername,ipassword,imail,igender,iage,iproblem,iproblem_value,ifitness) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}',{6},'{7}')", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstring, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        Session["connect_status"] = "connected";
        Response.Redirect("My_Plan.aspx");

    }

    else

    {
        if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count) > 0)
        {
            Session["subscribed"] = "exist";

            if ((ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count) > 0)
            {
                Session["mail"] = "exist";
                Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
            }

            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I created a sign up form and this code is used to insert the data into the database and check also for existing equal mail and username values.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? You've posted 73 lines of code, and left us to guess where the problem is. Ideally, reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: Also, you should read up on parameterized SQL **immediately** to avoid the SQL injection vulnerability that your code currently has (in multiple places).

Comment: Are you sure `ds.Tables` and `ds1.Tables` have at least one value?

Comment: one thing i should say-learn to debug your code.

Comment: whoah guys I am kind of a noob in coding and I just signed up to this website so I don't really know how the rules and stuff go around here.

Comment: Try adding `if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds1.Tables.Count > 0)` before `if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) || ...`

Comment: @CommandoMan - Jon Skeet's first question is still most important. What line in your code is throwing that error?

Comment: @AdamV - Actually, now it seems to be fixed for some odd reason. Though I don't get an error now, my validation doesn't seem to work- it enters the values into the database whether they exist or not.

Answer (score 3):

`string sqlstring1 = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{2}')", c);`

{2} doesn't exist as there is only one argument in the string.Format().
Note that I googled it which led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316409/index-zero-based-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-zero) (hint hint).

So change it to this:
`string sqlstring1 = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{0}')", c);`

and try again.

Comment: your'e right I actually changed that and it still didn't work- at was as if it skipped the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't identified the line the error is occurring on, I'm going to assume that the problem is with this line of code, because it's wrong:

```
string sqlstring1 = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{2}')", c);
```

The {2} should be a {0} because it's a zero based index and you've only told string.Format to expect one parameter.

Comment: That's probably not where the exception is being thrown although it may contribute to it.

Comment: your'e right I actually changed that and it still didn't work- it was as if it skipped the validation

Comment: Ok, in that case can you tell us on which line the exception is happening, please?

Comment: Actually, now it seems to be fixed for some odd reason. Though I don't get an error now, my validation doesn't seem to work- it enters the values into the database whether they exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

As others answered, the problem is your string.Format. But I'd also like to point out that [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) were added in C# 6 which would allow you to change

`string sqlstring1 = string.Format("select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{0}')", c);`

to

`string sqlstring1 = $"select * from iUsers_Table where (imail='{c}')"`

It's a much cleaner and more readable way to format strings and should help to avoid that easy to make mistake in the future.

**Edit:** Seeing as that didn't fix your exception, make sure `ds.Tables.Length` is greater than 0, anywhere you've got `ds.Tables[0]` will throw an exception if `ds.Tables` is empty.

I also noticed you missed some quotes in

```
sqlstring = string.Format("insert into iUsers_Table (iusername,ipassword,imail,igender,iage,iproblem,iproblem_value,ifitness) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}',{6},'{7}')", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
```

around `{6}` although I'm not sure that would cause the exception you're getting. Telling us where the exception occurred would help a great deal.

Comment: Actually, now it seems to be fixed for some odd reason. Though I don't get an error now, my validation doesn't seem to work- it enters the values into the database whether they exist or not. I also couldn't use the interpolated string you showed and I got an error when I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was a problem on another page.

Thanks everyone for commenting. :)