# Unexplained exception from SQL command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a REST web service running under IIS and am getting an odd exception thrown from a particular SQL command.

The query

```
insert into locations (lat, lon, dt, owner) 
values ('30', '-5', '20170107 16:40:17', 1)
```

works fine, but this one

```
update locations 
set dt = '20170107 16:37:18' 
where id = 12817
```

always throws an exception

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

`id` is the primary key. Both commands are sent using the same code structure:

```
query = string.Format(result = string.Format("Time updated for {0} at {2}", loc.Owner, DateTime.Now););

try
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, mapConnection))
    {
        successRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    .....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ....
}
finally
{
    ....
    mapConnection.Close(); 
}
```

If I send the same command direct to the server using SQL Server Enterprise Manager, the command completes as expected without errors. So what is asp.net complaining about?

Comment: Did you debug to find where the error is being thrown?

Comment: Let me see the code in `query = string.Format`

Comment: Your string.format is the problem. Can you share how you are building INSERT and UPDATE queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316409/index-zero-based-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-zero

Comment: I've added the code in the string format. But it wasn't thrwig the exception exactly where I thought, it was just after. I had  "if (successRows == 1)        result = string.Format("Time updated for {0} at {2}", loc.Owner, DateTime.Now);" - so that's the error there. So solved - thanks @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

Look at your string.format. You don't have enough items passed into  it:

```
string.Format("Time updated for {0} at {2}", loc.Owner, DateTime.Now)
```

You have positions for {0} and {2}. You don't list a {1} but it's implied. So now the format is expecting 3 items passed into it and you're only passing in two. Change your format to:

```
string.Format("Time updated for {0} at {1}", loc.Owner, DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but as I said in my comment above I found the error after @Carcigenicate suggested checking where the exception was thrown. Sorry I didn't explicitly put the correction in my reply.